# Weak equivalence testable on invariant open covers?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f\colon X\rightarrow X'$ be a continuous map between two spaces $X,X'$, which might be arbitrary wild, especially I don't want to work in any convenient category of topological spaces. Let $X=U\cup V$ and $X'=U'\cup V'$ be an open covers such that $f(U)\subseteq U'$ and $f(V)\subseteq V'$ holds.

Consider the following claim.

> If the three restrictions $f\colon U\rightarrow V$, $f\colon V\rightarrow V'$ and $f\colon U\cap U'\rightarrow V\cap V'$ are weak homotopy equivalences, then so is $f\colon X\rightarrow X'$.

1. Is this claim true in general? If not, are there mild assumptions on $X$, $X'$ or $X$ and $X'$, such that the claim holds, e.g. does the claim hold if $X$ and $X'$ are Hausdorff spaces?
2. What about the corresponding claim with homotopy equivalences instead of weak equivalences?

Comment: What is the word "invariant" indicating in the title?

Comment: $f$ preserves the chosen open covers.

Comment: One possible condition to impose is that the inclusions $U \cap V \to U$, $U \cap V \to V$, $U' \cap V' \to U'$ and $U' \cap V' \to V'$ are cofibrations. Unfortunately, for Hausdorff spaces, cofibrations are closed embeddings.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that. Since I am mainly interested in Hausdorff spaces, this is not useful to me.

Comment: This question continuous on http://mathoverflow.net/questions/200771/when-are-weak-homotopy-equivalence-testable-on-open-covers .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to leave this question open:

Answers can be found at the [sequel of this question on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200771/when-are-weak-homotopy-equivalence-testable-on-open-covers) .